# How to set WKInterfaceButton font programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-watch

Currently I can adjust the font type and size via storyboard. However, I want to set `WKInterfaceButton` font programmatically for different scenarios.

Comment: Missing programming language tag and some code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via `NSAttributedString`

```
UIFont * buttonFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier-Bold" size:6];
NSAttributedString *buttonText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString : @"Your button title" attributes : @{ NSKernAttributeName : @2.0, NSFontAttributeName : buttonFont}];
[self.button setAttributedTitle:buttonText];
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift-3 NSAttributedString for updating attributes  :**

```
func changeAttributeOfText() {
        let paragraphStyle =  NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        let attributes:Dictionary = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle ,  NSFontAttributeName:font ]
        let attributeString:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "HELLO", attributes: attributes)
         buttonOutlet.setAttributedTitle(attributeString)
    }
```

[Demo App](https://github.com/shrawan2015/Application-Demo-StackOverFlow/tree/master/WatchOS)